# Issues with Left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to cut down on rows in a report I'm building. I have an Address table and an asset table that I for the most part I have 2 or more different assets per premise. I would like to just have the premise as one line and the assets to the right on the same line. However, my current SQL only returns rows were I have 2 assets for a premise.

So I rewrote it to do a left outer join but it won't run..

Help!

```
Error - ORA-00904: "SP"."SVC_PT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 32
```

Query

```
SELECT SP.svc_pt_id,
       SP.device_id,
       DV.mfg_serial_num,
       dc.name,
       Substr(dc.name, 26),
       ctpt.ctpt_name,
       ctpt.ctpt_multipler,
       ctpt.ctpt_id
FROM   eip.svc_pt_device_rel SP,
       eip.device_class dc,
       eip.device DV
       left outer join (SELECT SP.svc_pt_id        ctpt_svc_pt_id,
                               SP.device_id        CTPT_ID,
                               dc.name             CTPT_name,
                               Substr(dc.name, 26) CTPT_multipler
                        FROM   eip.svc_pt_device_rel SP,
                               eip.device_class dc,
                               eip.device DV
                        WHERE  SP.eff_start_time < To_date('20170930','YYYYMMDD') + 1
                               AND SP.eff_end_time IS NULL
                               AND dc.id = DV.device_class_id
                               AND DV.id = SP.device_id
                               AND dc.name LIKE '%CT/PT%'
                        ORDER  BY SP.svc_pt_id) ctpt
                    ON ctpt_svc_pt_id = SP.svc_pt_id    
WHERE  SP.eff_start_time < To_date('20170930', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1
       AND SP.eff_end_time IS NULL
       AND dc.id = DV.device_class_id
       AND DV.id = SP.device_id
       AND dc.name NOT LIKE '%CT/PT%'
--and SP.SVC_PT_ID = ctpt.ctpt_svc_pt_id(+)
ORDER  BY SP.svc_pt_id;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: sounds like maybe you want an AGGREGATE function like LIST_AGG

Comment: Does the column `scv_pt_id` exist in the table `svc_pt_device_rel` in the schema `eip`? Do you have the permissions necessary to access this table from the schema you're currently using? Furthermore you're mixing implicit and explicit join syntax which could easily be causing your error. Just use the explicit syntax.

Comment: Your FROM clause mixes old-style comma joins with ANSi-92 explicit joins. You cannot mix them: that is why you get the ORA-00904 error on `SP.svc_pt_id` which obviously exists. So, choose either commas with a WHERE clause on explicit joins with the ON clause, and stick to your choice for the whole of the FROM clause. Probably you should choose to use the ANSI 92 syntax, because (as you've found) it makes outer joins so much easier to write and understand.